# Electrical Physics: Rank the charge densities in the blocks

Tags: homework-and-exercises, electrostatics, charge, insulators

Im just beginning to learn about electrical physics. Im a bit confused with ranking the charge density. I think Im suppose to compare the ratios of the blocks. Would block E have the Greatest charge density because its 'po' is doubled while the rest of the block is the same?

I appreciate the help I can get.

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

$\text {volume charge density} \;(\rho )= \dfrac {\text{charge}\;(Q)}{\text {volume}\;(V)}$

Comment: .For block D and E would I find Q since density is given? they both end up having the same Q. Would I just state that block E has the greater charge density of the two?